# Changing the red edit button accessory view in a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I would like to draw my own edit accessory view instead of the red minus button in a UITableView.

Strangely setting any of them in tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: has no effect

```
    cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;        
    cell.editingAccessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel"]];
```

since the button is set before calls to that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the editing controls to be seen, editing needs to be enabled in the table view.

Try sending this to the table view: - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/setEditing:animated:

Comment: I remember it took me awhile to get it working the first time. You may want to review the Table View Programming guide [link] (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451).

I think you will need to implement a few more methods from the UITableViewDataSource Protocol, mainly – tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:. I think that is it.